# Encrypting using AesCryptoServiceProvider in c# is decrypting file to different size

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I must encrypt files using AES256CBC.

The problem is when ever I encrypt a file, and decrypt it, it changes the decrypted filesize slighty.

One file starts at 64920KB and ends up at 65536KB

This is my encryption method:

```
 public static void Encrypt(FileStream fileWriteStream, 
            FileStream fileReadStream, 
            byte[] key, 
            byte[] iv)
        {
            const int megabyte = 1024 * 1024;

            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;  //ive tried all different padding types

            using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fileWriteStream, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {

                    using (fileReadStream)
                    {
                        var bytesToRead = megabyte < fileReadStream.Length ? (int)megabyte : (int)fileReadStream.Length;

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];

                        fileReadStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        int bytesRead = fileReadStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                        while (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                            var bytesLeft = fileReadStream.Length - bytesRead;
                            bytesToRead = bytesLeft > megabyte ? megabyte : (int)bytesLeft;

                            bytesRead = fileReadStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                        }
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

and this is how I am decrypting

```
// Decrypt a string into a string using a key and an IV 
        public static byte[] DecryptToBytes(byte[] cipherBytes, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
        {
            byte[] plainBytes;
            // Instantiate a new Aes object to perform string symmetric encryption
            Aes encryptor = Aes.Create();

            encryptor.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            // Set key and IV
            encryptor.IV = iv;

            byte[] aesKey = new byte[32];
            Array.Copy(key, 0, aesKey, 0, 32);
            encryptor.Key = aesKey;


            // Instantiate a new MemoryStream object to contain the encrypted bytes
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            // Instantiate a new encryptor from our Aes object
            ICryptoTransform aesDecryptor = encryptor.CreateDecryptor();

            // Instantiate a new CryptoStream object to process the data and write it to the 
            // memory stream
            CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, aesDecryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            try
            {
                // Decrypt the input ciphertext string
                cryptoStream.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);

                // Complete the decryption process
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();

                // Convert the decrypted data from a MemoryStream to a byte array
                plainBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close both the MemoryStream and the CryptoStream
                memoryStream.Close();
                cryptoStream.Close();
            }

            // Return the decrypted data as a string
            return plainBytes;


        }
```

My test is fired using:

```
//tests only
var encryptedFile = @"C:\temp\encrypter\file.msi.encrypted";
            var fileWrite = new FileStream(encryptedFile, FileMode.Create);

            var encryptionKey = new byte[32] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            var iv = new byte[16] { 128, 0, 112, 0, 96, 0, 80, 0, 64, 0, 48, 0, 32, 0, 16, 0 };

            EncryptorUtil.Encrypt(fileWrite, fileStream, encryptionKey, iv);
            var decryptBytes = EncryptorUtil.DecryptToBytes(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(encryptedFile), encryptionKey, iv);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\encrypter\file.msi", decryptBytes);
```

Comment: Its a bit conspicuous that the size ends at 65535 (max value for 2 bytes) - my guess is, that the Decryptor (or rather the stream) has reserved this space. You could try *FlushFinalBlock()* on the Cryptostream, before closing.

Comment: I would really recommend 1) take `Stream` instead of `FileStream`, 2) Make both encryption and decryption methods take `Stream` as input, 3) Add optional overloads for each method that convert between `byte[]` and `Stream`. 4) use `Stream.CopyTo` to copy between streams, instead of writing this yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Ok I have figured it out myself:

```
 public static void Encrypt(FileStream fileWriteStream, 
            FileStream fileReadStream, 
            byte[] key, 
            byte[] iv)
        {
            const int megabyte = 1024 * 1024;

            AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
            aes.Key = key;
            aes.IV = iv;
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;  //ive tried all different padding types
            

            using (ICryptoTransform encrypt = aes.CreateEncryptor())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fileWriteStream, encrypt, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {

                    using (fileReadStream)
                    {
                        var bytesToRead = megabyte < fileReadStream.Length ? (int)megabyte : (int)fileReadStream.Length;

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesToRead];

                        fileReadStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        int bytesRead = fileReadStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                        var totalBytesRead = bytesRead;
                        while (bytesRead > 0)
                        {
                            cs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);

                            var bytesLeft = fileReadStream.Length - totalBytesRead;
                            bytesToRead = bytesLeft > megabyte ? megabyte : (int)bytesLeft;

                            bytesRead = fileReadStream.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
                            totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                        }
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This does not actually explain what the problem was, and is unlikely to help anyone else. And it still uses a manual copy-loop instead of just using `Stream.CopyTo`.